# Force a 404 from a template in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, http-status-code-404, gatsby

I’ve got a page `src/pages/drafts.js` that that I render some draft posts from, but only locally.

So, when `NODE_ENV` is production I’d like the route `/drafts` to be a 404.

```js
import React from 'react'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  // Invoke 404 somehow...
}

const MyComponent = () => <span>smth</span>
```

I can cancel the rendering in the component by returning null.

```js
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <span>smth</span>
  )
}
```

But that’s suboptimal in many ways.

I could also navigate the 404 page:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'

const MyComponent = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
      navigate('/404');
    }
  })

  return (
    <span>smth</span>
  )
}
```

This works, but if you load the route `/404` the HTTP status code is 200 and not 404.

I guess my question is, is there a way to to do a 404 before the template loads? Or somehow remove `src/pages/drafts.js` in a non development env?

Comment: That client side redirect might just work pretty well... Gatsby creates `public/drafts/index.html` though, but that's just empty.

Answer (score 2):

Just import it and return it is as another React component:

```
import React from 'react'
import NotFound from '/path/to/404/page'

const Drafts = () => {

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
     return <NotFound />;
   }

  return (
     <span>smth</span>
   )
}


export default Drafts
```

You can also make someway automatic:

```
import React from 'react'
import NotFound from '/path/to/404/page'

const Drafts = () => {
   let RenderPage= <span>smth</span>; 
 
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
     RenderPage = NotFound;
   }
 }


export default RenderPage
```

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on Ferran Buireu’s answer: import the 404, and then export based on the environment:

```
// src/pages/drafts.js
import React from 'react'
import NotFound from './404'

const Drafts = () => {
  return (
    <span>smth</span>
  )
}

export default process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? NotFound : Drafts
```

The returned `404` page has a `200` status code, which might or not be a problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer since doesn't make sense that you answer your own question based on mine. I've added a new approach. It's better to return a simple component instead of making a ternary condition in the export